# Automatic failover with SQL mirroring and connection strings

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, failover, mirroring

I have 3 servers set up for SQL mirroring and automatic failover using a witness server. This works as expected.

Now my application that connects to the database, seems to have a problem when a failover occurs - I need to manually intervene and change connection strings for it to connect again.
The best solution I've found so far involves using `Failover Partner` parameter of the connection string, however it's neither intuitive nor complete: `Data Source="Mirror";Failover Partner="Principal"` [found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/12/08/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup.aspx).

From the example in the blog above (scenario #3) when the first failover occurs, and principal (failover partner) is unavailable, data source is used instead (which is the new principal). If it fails again (and I only tried within a limited period), it then comes up with an error message. This happens because the connection string is cached, so until this is refreshed, it will keep coming out with an error (it seems connection string refreshes ~5 mins after it encounters an error). If after failover I swap data source and failover partner, I will have one more silent failover again.

Is there a way to achieve fully automatic failover for applications that use mirroring databases too (without ever seeing the error)?

I can see potential workarounds using custom scripts that would poll currently active database node name and adjust connection string accordingly, however it seems like an overkill at the moment.

Comment: The link above has gone dead. For anyone looking for it, this one still works: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/archive/blogs/spike/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the blog post here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/12/15/running-a-database-mirror-setup-with-the-sqlbrowser-service-off-may-produce-unexpected-results.aspx

It explains what is happening, the failover partner is actually being read from the sql server not from your config. Run the query in that post to find out what is actually being used as the failover server. It will probably be a machine name that is not discoverable from where your client is running.

Comment: Then why does it work as expected with connection pooling off?

Comment: When connection pooling is on connections that are made to the primary, that has the secondary (from the server) stored with it, will be retained for future use. These are the ones that do not fail over. With connection pooling turned off a new connection is created and read from the config each time. These will work as it cannot connect to the primary so uses the failover from config not the primary server value for failover.

Comment: See here for more detail: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/12/08/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup.aspx

Comment: From the second link: "...the SQL Server will send the failover partner to the client...". In my situation, regardless of which server was the primary one, the first failover worked correctly, the second one didn't. From this I assume the failover partner was resolved correctly, but why only once? Perhaps that's unclear from my question.

Comment: In your connection string you are setting the Data Source as the Mirror and the Failover Partner as the Principal. So every time you call Connection.Open() it will go to your connection string find "Mirror" try to connect to that, get refused as this is running as the mirror not the pricipal. Then It will try the Failover Partner from your connection string, this is set to "Priciple" as this is actually the principle that will work.

Comment: In this case there is no setting of a failover partner in cache as it will always be trying the 2 from the connection string as the first one fails. Now when a failover occurs it will successfully connect to what you have specified as "Mirror" and read the failover from that server. Which is why, the 2nd failover (or fail back) does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the application pool in the case a failover has happened. Not very nice I know ;-)

```cs
  // ClearAllPools resets (or empties) the connection pool. 
  // If there are connections in use at the time of the call, 
  // they are marked appropriately and will be discarded 
  // (instead of being returned to the pool) when Close is called on them.
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

We use it when we change an underlying server via SQL Server alias, to enforce a "refresh" of the server name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools.aspx

Comment: How can I know when a failover has happened? In theory if my application is aware of the underlying database failing over I could just change connection strings.

Comment: Not sure how you know about a happened failover... Do you need to specify 2 servers in your connection string? Primary and Mirror?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to turn connection pooling off `Pooling="false"`

Whilst this has minimal impact on small applications, I haven't tested it with applications that receive hundreds of requests per minute (or more) and not sure what the implications are. Anyone care to comment?

Comment: how long did you wait for failover to occur in your original setup?   in my recent experience, it seems you have to wait for all connections in the pool that were pointing to the original principal to expire before it realizes that the primary is down and tries to connect to the failover partner.   this was up to 15 mins in some of my apps.

Comment: I don't remember to be honest, but the requirement was to have nearly 0 downtime, so I couldn't wait for that long anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this connectionString:

`connectionString="Data Source=[MSSQLPrincipalServerIP,MSSQLPORT];Failover Partner=[MSSQLMirrorServerIP,MSSQLPORT];Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=userName; Password=userPassword.; Connection Timeout=15;"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net development, you can try to use ObjAdoDBLib or PigSQLSrvLib and PigSQLSrvCoreLib, and the code will become simple.

***Example code:***

New object
ObjAdoDBLib

> Me.ConnSQLSrv = New ConnSQLSrv(Me.DBSrv, Me.MirrDBSrv, Me.CurrDB, Me.DBUser, Me.DBPwd, Me.ProviderSQLSrv)

PigSQLSrvLib or PigSQLSrvCoreLib

> Me.ConnSQLSrv = New ConnSQLSrv(Me.DBSrv, Me.MirrDBSrv, Me.CurrDB, Me.DBUser, Me.DBPwd)

Execute this method to automatically connect to the online database after the mirror database fails over.

> Me.ConnSQLSrv.OpenOrKeepActive

***For more information, see the relevant links.***

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjAdoDBLib/

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/PigSQLSrvLib/

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/PigSQLSrvCoreLib/