SQL Server timeout during 2 minutes when scaling up my ASP.NET Core application in AWS ECS
I'm facing an issue with my ASP.NET Core 6 application running on AWS ECS (Fargate).
My app uses a SQL client to perform SQL requests. When for example 10 instances are running, everything is working well.
But, in order to scale properly my service with the volume of traffic, I have a job which is running and scaling my ECS service. When for example I expect much more traffic, the job will scale the number of tasks from 10 to 15.
The problem comes after the Blue/Green deployment. Once my new tasks are up (health checks are ok), the application load balancer sends traffic to new tasks. But during the first two minutes after new tasks began to receive traffic, I'm facing SQL timeouts. After this amount of time, timeouts disappear and new tasks manage properly SQL requests.
Here are the logs from my new tasks :

I don't understand why I'm facing SQL timeouts, but only at the beginning of my application runtime.
What I already tried to do :

Specifying SQL Server port in my connection string
Setting the Min Pool Size attribute to 100 in my connection string
Opening a first SqlDbConnection in my Program.cs in order to resolve the domain name of my SQL Server listener

What can I do to not get these timeouts anymore?

Where is SQL Server running? RDS?

I have 2 environments, one on an EC2 instance and another on RDS. And I'm facing this issue on both

Sounds like the environment for those tasks isn't fully up until 2 minutes? For example your network. Shouldn't health check include network stuff?

As I said before, I've tried to connect to my db instance in my application startup (using SqlDbConnection), and it's working fine. So from a network point of view it seems that everything is configured to communicate properly with the database

So, you have a working connection at startup, but then it stops working as soon as you turn on the routing? Sounds fishy

Yes, that's why I don't understand anything of what's happening

What's SqlDbConnection? Given the error messages in your screen shot (which should have been included as text, by the way, not screen shots) it sounds like a 3rd party wrapper class around the legacy System.Data.SqlClient objects that haven't received feature updates since 2019. Since you're not using .NET Framework any more why aren't you using the more modern and actively developed Microsoft.Data.SqlClient classes?

We are using an internal wrapper which is used and common to apps running on .NET Framework and .NET Core. That's the main reason. I've migrated to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but it does not change anything.
But, I managed to potentialy solve the issue by executing a basic SQL command in my application startup (SELECT 1;). It seems that doing a first request before receiving traffic (thousand of HTTP requests, so thousands of SQL requests) solves the issue : I don't receive any timeouts anymore

@AlwaysLearning which should have been included as text, by the way, not screen shots sorry mate I'm not spending my whole life on StackOverflow so I'm not aware with all the best practices. I'll include logs as text in the future.

It seems that receiving traffic without having at least one time executed a SQL request causes these timeouts.
Executing a first SQL request during application startup solved the issue.
What I suggest :

Integrate a database health check in your health checks (in my case that's not what I want).
Or execute a simple SQL request during application startup SELECT 1;

I released the fix in production, and I don't have any timeouts anymore.
If anyone has an explanation of why it works like this ? (even if yes, I agree it's a dirty solution)

"It seems that receiving traffic without having at least one time executed a SQL request causes these timeouts." - that's seems like a symptom and not the actual cause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606720/automatic-failover-with-sql-mirroring-and-connection-strings   I believe you need to alter the connection string and set MultiSubnetFailover  to “TRUE.” https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/connection-timeouts-in-multi-subnet-availability-group/ba-p/318334

Thanks for your comment, but the MultiSubnetFailover property was already set to "True" and it was not working like that
